# Error in return type

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have written a formula field of data type `DATETIME` and return type text

```
IF((ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Completed')),NOW(),'')
```

but error occurred states

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'IF()'. Expected
>   DateTime, received Text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return type of your formula field is `Text`, that is why you have to return `Text` types in both results: true and false of `IF` formula. Add `TEXT` formula for returned `NOW()`

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Completed'), TEXT(NOW()), null)
```

---

returned result of `TEXT(NOW())` is in GMT time

Comment: I tried it too but got Error: Formula result is data type (DateTime), incompatible with expected data type (Text).

Comment: @Swathi I have updated my answer, try it.

Comment: Get rid of the extra parentheses. They seem to be screwing you up too. I think you close your `IF` early.

Comment: Thanks! it worked but the time is getting wrong. Not showing current time

Comment: @Swathi it is showing correct GMT

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskiy i want the time to be in est format like 2/4/2017 8:38 AM

Comment: @Swathi then change return type from Text to Date/TIme